# Need Alternative to SQL AVG() for Obvient BI tool

Tags: sql, oracle

I am reading 2 fields from 1 table.

StartKey and Mins

Image below shows my current output result on left and what I need on right.
[image]

**Here is my Query**

```
Select
       StartKey,
       Duration as Mins
From   TableA
Where  Flag = 0
Order by StartKey
```

I know I can use `avg(duration)`, but if I use that, Obvient, the software I am using to write and display the query, won't let me take the average of column Mins Avg itself.

[image]

This error I get after I manually insterted average code of column in CS file and then I try to edit column properties.
[image]

Comment: did you use GROUP BY together with avg?

Comment: What is the datatype of duration then? It looks to be a number and so `avg(duration)` should work. I assume that `duration` and `mins` are the same as it's not at all clear from your question...

Comment: Yes, I have used Avg(duration) then Group by startkey, but if I use this I can't use built tool to take average of whole column itself.

Comment: @Ben I have fixed my query plz take alook, and duration is just showing type `number`

Answer (score 2):

First, let me make sure I understand your problem.

You are using the SQL from your post while building something in Obvient which appears to be a Business Intelligence platform. The problem you are having is that you are unable to perform an average function in Obvient on the column of averages in your SQL query.

If that is correct, you should use your SQL query to create a view in the database which should appear to Obvient as a table and may allow you to perform the averaging function. I can't say for certain that this will solve your issue having never used Obvient, but give that a try and let us know how that works for you.

Comment: You are correct... and Thanks, I will definitely try that. this is what I ended up doing. I wrote query as I posted original without avg() function, and I use built function to take average of whole column(it generate code in some file (C program code), I saved that code in another file), so after I go the code to take the average, I added function in my query which takes average for startkey, and I just went to the file it generated again and pasted the C code in there and it worked for me. I will post image error it gives me if I try to edit the generated file(gives error

Comment: because Obvient doesn't support avg() with group by.) I kind of over wrote the C file.

Comment: So Obvient generates reports as C programs?

Comment: Yes, but most of back end Obvient user won't know this, because all they do is write query in Obvient software, it publishes on web.

Comment: Check last Error image I uploaded, it is ORA Error.

Comment: You would need to post the C code for us to figure out what is causing the error. I'm under the impression that modifying the C files is going to be a much more difficult road than making the view, so I would recommend you try the view before returning to this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I'm missing something, but to get your desired results, this should work:

```
Select
       StartKey,
       AVG(Duration) as Mins
From   TableA
Where  Flag = 0
Group By StartKey
Order by StartKey
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7a8b3/3).

If your goal is to get the AVG(Mins) from the above query, you could use a subquery to return that:

```
Select AVG(Mins)
FROM (
   SELECT
       StartKey,
       AVG(Duration) as Mins
    From   TableA
    Group By StartKey
    ) t
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7a8b3/6):

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, I am currently using what you have posted, but if I use AVG(Duration), software I am writing query in won't allow me to take average of column Mins(duration). is there any of way of doing this?

Comment: What is your desired output?  I have added the SQL Fiddle above.

Comment: @Mowgli, which software are you using?

Comment: If there is way to take average of startkey without using avg. that will solve my problem.

Comment: Well, there may be a more elegant solution as I'm getting tired, but you could always run the first query and union the results of the second query (just add a blank column to the second query).  Maybe I'm still misunderstanding, but that would produce results similar to your latest picture.